# Installshield suite project logging

Tags: logging, installshield, suite

Is there any way that the logging of Installshield suite setup.exe file can be automatic? I can create a batch file that does:
Setup.exe /debuglog"C:\logpath\SomeLog.log"
but I'd rather setup.exe do it on its own.
Is it possible?

Comment: http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield18helplib/stesetupexeparam.htm